# exclude a changelist from p4 sync

Tags: perforce, synchronization

Is there any easy way to exclude a specific changelist from `p4 sync`?

I want to sync up my code, but I don't want to fetch the changes from changelist #1337

Like: `p4 sync //depot/source/... - //depot/source/...#1337`?

Comment: For clarification: Is #1337 something in between or the last change?

Comment: Surely use branches to avoid this level of pain?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish this is just sync to head, and then use the 'Back out submitted changelist' function in P4V ('Submitted' pane, right-click the undesired changelist, select 'Back out submitted changelist').

This will create a new pending changelist in your workspace with the undesired changes removed.

Comment: Caveat: files modified by the undesired changelist will now be at the revision preceding the undesired changelist, and any subsequent changes to those files will also be gone. But you can then do an interactive resolve and manually pull in any new changes that you need.

Comment: This also fails, if you have one of those changed files in edit mode :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by syncing to a range and using two commands to "skip" the changelist.

```
p4 sync //depot/source/... - //depot/source/...@0,@1337
p4 sync //depot/source/... - //depot/source/...@1337,#head
```

Note: you may have to specify the changelist on either side of the one you want to skip - not sure if the range is inclusive.

HTH,

Dennis

Comment: The problem with this method is if a file modified by changelist 1337 is also modified by a subsequent changelist, that file will end up with changes in CL 1337 anyway.

Comment: @Heath: I agree. It is not ideal. 

I do not understand why the OP wants to exclude a specific changelist - the best way to handle this is to sync to #head and the backout the changelist, then either manually handle future resolves or submit the changes. 

However if for some reason you are unable to submit, then create a branch and perform the backout of changelist there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this should work depending on what you want to do.  Man I really miss git :(

If you simply want to sync and temporarily ignore a changelist you can do what the first reply said and back out the change list.  Just remember to not check that change list in unless you want to wipe out the ignored changelist for the branch.  However this approach will not work if you need to make changes to files that exist in the ignored changelist.

If you need to work with the same files from the ignored changelist you can do the following.  One thing to note however, is that the ignored changelist will be pulled out of the remote branch until you are ok with them being in your code. (there is one other option but requires someone else to do something) 
If you want to ignore a change list, and not get rid of it completely but simply be able to work on your code with it off to the side, the following will work.

Back out the changelist as previously stated.
Submit the backed out changelist to wipe out the changes in the remote branch. (don't worry)

Now do another back out but this time back out the chagelist created by the previous back out and shelve it.  This back out of the back out will be a pending change list that is basically a copy of the one you wanted to ignore.  Once its shelved you can go about your work, even in the same files.  The down side is that now the ignored changelist only exist on your work space and its up to you to submit it or decide what to do with it at some point.

You can keep the ignored change list shelved until you know what you want to do with it.  If, after you work on your code, you want to re integrate that chagelist and merge it with yours you can simply unshelf it and resolve conflicts.

So the (other option)
You could do the above with help from another dev with a perforce account (perhaps the one who's changelist you want to ignore) in this case you could have them back out the changelist and submit, then you could sync, then they could back out their back out.  In this case the remote branch would not need to stay in weird state while you worked on your code.  The big downside is, that you would have to do this every time you wanted to sync.

A better option would be branching before an issue like this arrises but that is not as easy or light weight in perforce as it is in git.

Hope one of these options help or spark a finale and perfect solution from some one else.